# aspect ratio is lost when using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, screen, aspect-ratio

I am trying to make a square larger by using createScaledBitmap. However, the square becomes a rectangle with width longer than height. What is the proper way to do this in order to keep the aspect ratio constant?

```
public Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    scaledBitmapW = (int)(dm.widthPixels/(10)); *//make the square just 1/10 of the screen width*
    scaledBitmapH = (int)(scaledBitmapW*(bitmap.getHeight()/bitmap.getWidth()));
    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledBitmapW, scaledBitmapH, true);
    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Comment: When you run this, what are your values for `bitmap.getHeight()` and `bitmap.getWidth()`? They should be the same if your input is square, and so there's no point in dividing them, so `scaledBitmapH` should be equal to `scaledBitmapW`.

Comment: the bitmap is actually a rectangle with a square in the middle of the rectangle, so bitmap.getHeight() does not equal to bitmap.getWidth. @CommonsWare